# How to find classmates of student C who are taking any of the classes that C is taking, in SQL?

Tags: sql, union

There are two tables, `students` and `courses`. The `students` table has `name`, `age` and `ssn`.

`Courses` has `ssn` and `Course`.

Now the `ssn` in the `courses` table is NOT unique but the one in `students` is primary key.

I need to find out the students who are taking any of the classes that student `C` is taking (including `C`'s name as well in the resulting solution).

It's a challenge problem so I can just not mind it but I want to find out what the solution is.

So far I've tried to use a `union` operator like this :

```
SELECT ssn
FROM courses
UNION SELECT ssn
FROM students
WHERE name =  'c'
```

All this does is it returns all the ssns from the table `courses`. The question asks us to effectively find the set UNION of the both tables to determine the solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for the students who are taking at least one class in common with Student C, or are you looking for students who are taking exactly the same list of classes as Student C?  Since you've just accepted an answer that does the former (and much simpler) query, I have to assume you're dealing with 'Students who are taking any classes in common with Student C'.

Comment: Yes I am looking for students that are taking any classes that the student C is also taking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s2.ssn, s2.name
    FROM students s1
        INNER JOIN courses c1  /* Find all courses taken by student 'c' */
            ON s1.ssn = c1.ssn
        INNER JOIN courses c2  /* Find all students in all of c's courses */
            ON c1.course = c2.course
        INNER JOIN students s2 /* Get the details for each of those students */
            ON c2.ssn = s2.ssn
    WHERE s1.name = 'c'
```

Comment: @MahiVattekat: I added a DISTINCT to my answer to address that requirement.

Comment: So distinct makes it unique...
What does the "inner join courses c1 on s1.ssn = c1.ssn" and the rest mean?

Comment: By the way this actually worked!Is there any way to do this problem using a union operator though?

Comment: what are s1,s2,c1 and c2? are they aliases?

Comment: @MahiVattekat Glad to help. I don't see a way to do this with UNIONs. I certainly wouldn't tackle the problem that way. Yes, s1, s2, ... are aliases for the tables.

Comment: Why would you use two aliases for one table though?Wouldnt it be better if it were just one ?

Comment: @MahiVattekat: You need two different aliases because I am using each table twice, each time for a different purpose, as indicated in the comments I included in my answer.

Comment: Doesn't this find all the students who take any one course in common with Student C?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, that is the way I interpreted the question.

Comment: yes that is the question and that is the answer I was looking for.Thank you!

Comment: NP: Since your answer is accepted, I assume that must be what the OP is wanting, too.  It wasn't the way I read the question, but it is a lot simpler than the alternative.

Comment: Agree with @JonathanLeffler, the question was somewhat ambiguous. I've edited the original post now to reflect the question more accurately. Well done on figuring it out before the OP's clarification!

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct c1.ssn, s1.name from courses c1   // find distinct ssn and name for courses X (defined below)
inner join students s1 on c1.ssn=s1.ssn
where c1.course  in 
(select course
 from courses     // use to find all courses (say X) for student c
where ssn =
(select ssn from students where name='c'))  // find ssn of student
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what does the c in c.ssn and the s in s.name and dbo mean?

Comment: dbo is owner of tables, c is alias for table courses, c.ssn means ssn in table courses, similarly s is alias for table students, s.name means name column in students table

Comment: when i put this it says access denied. Am i supposed to put my (owner)name on dbo?

Comment: i modified the query and removed owner so that it will take what ever owner you described.